# Why does `pg_lsclusters` not list my Postgres cluster?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2

1. I `apt-get` installed Postgres 9.2.4 (using PPA).
2. I used `pg_dropcluster --stop 9.2 main` to remove the default database cluster, because I intended on creating a new cluster on a separate SSD volume (a Rackspace block storage volume) that was just mounted.
3. I created that new cluster whose data resides on my SSD volume and  started it (`ps` shows all the normal Postgres processes running for that new cluster and I'm able to open a Postgres shell and run SQL - i.e., it's running fine). Now when I run `pg_lsclusters` there are none listed.

The `main` cluster listed just fine before I deleted it. Why won't my new cluster show up, even when it's running? I've even rebooted the server (just in case).

Comment: Well, how did you create the new cluster? Also, host OS and version? Ubuntu ... ? Debian ... ? Other? (Not many distros use `pg_wrapper` though)

Comment: @CraigRinger - I used `initdb -D  /the/dir/` - I think I just realized that I should have used `pg_createcluster -d /the/dir/` shouldn't I have? Are they both the same, minus whatever extra meta data that Postgres stores about the cluster? (I'm on Ubuntu 12.04.2)

Comment: Wow, indeed that is the case - and what an awesome tool with such a simple syntax as `pg_ctlcluster 9.2 mycluster start`

Comment: Yep, you got it - if you want to use `pg_wrapper` you have to do so consistently.

Comment: @CraigRinger - thanks. If you put that into an answer (I made one, but it's not terrific), I'll accept yours and remove mine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In order to use these postgres common tools with a cluster, they need to be used consistently. You would use `pg_createcluster -d /path/to/data`, instead of `initdb`. `pg_createcluster` adds the cluster to `postgres-common` in order to facilitate these handy operations. It is a wrapper, just like `pg_ctlcluster`, around the lower-level tools (e.g., `initdb` and `pg_ctl`), providing access from one place to operating on all of your clusters. It also has some defaults, such as an automatically configured log location based on the cluster name. this means you don't have to use `-l /var/log/my-custom.log` when you're creating or starting the server.